# Validating input field as Numeric and certain picture size

Tags: javascript

I have a form with an input text field and a "submit" button.

Before i submit, i need to validate that the input text is of type numeric and contain a number 12 digits.
How can i do it using JavaScript?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, i mean 12 digits number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regexp:

```
// assuming input is reference to your input field
if (/^[0-9]{12}$/.test(input.value) === true) {....}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can easily do it with regex:

```
if ( /^[0-9]{12}$/.test(someInput.value) ) { ... }
```

In fact, this won't be necessary if your application is to be used on the browsers [**supporting**](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs.html#t12) `pattern` attribute for `input` elements:

```
<input name="twelve_digits" pattern="[0-9]{12}" 
       title="please supply twelve digits" />
```

Note the difference: you have to specify anchors in the regex pattern (as otherwise any string that contains sequence of twelve digits would pass it), but they are supplied automatically when `pattern` value is parsed.

Comment: you are missing the closing parentheses on your if statement